# How can I access the auto-created document ID when creating a new Firestore document in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to return the document id when I create it. Since Firebase functions are async the return value is not completed until the query is done.  How can I prevent this so I can wait to get the value when the query is done?

This function create the document is located in a service:

```
public makeDoc(title: string, score: number): any{

    const fields = {
      title: title,
      score: number
    }

   this.db.collection('saved').add(fields)
   .then(function(ref) {
     console.log(ref.id);
     return ref.id;
     })

  }
```

I call this from a function which is located in a component:

```
onCreate() {
      const str = this.createService.makeDoc(this.title, this.score);
    console.log(str);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
const fields = {
      title: title,
      score: number
    }


  var newFieldsRef = this.db.collection('saved').push();
  this.db.collection('saved').child(newFieldsRef).set(fields);

  var id = newFieldsRef.toString();
```

Comment: It returns an error -> Property 'push' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollection<unknown>'

Comment: @ManWeb how do you define db?

Comment: @MichailKozlova I had refined as ->   private db: AngularFirestore

Comment: @ManWeb ok, sorry, confused with Firebase Database, Firestore really doesn't have push() fuction

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to prevent waiting until the query is done, you should embrace the use of promises here.

First, if you haven't, make sure you import the `firestore` namespace in the service:

`import { firestore } from 'firebase';`

Now, for your service:

I had to slightly change your `makeDoc` method as the `fields` object wasn't being created in a valid way (e.g. reusing the `number` type):

```js
public makeDoc(titleParam: string, scoreParam: number): Promise<firestore.DocumentReference> {
  const fields = {
    title: titleParam,
    score: scoreParam
  };

  return this.db.collection('saved').add(fields);
}
```

This now returns a `Promise<DocumentReference>` which, when resolved, the reference will point to the created document.

Now, the call to it in onCreate looks like:

```js
onCreate() {
  this.createService.makeDoc('myTitle', 123)
    .then((ref) => { console.log(ref.id); })
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
}
```

And this will log the id as soon as it is available.